# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 only with macports GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, gcc

I get an error when compiling some C++ code from a private repository using gcc. I will thus unfortunately not be able to share the code. The error is `duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`:

```
g++ -o obj/manager.o -c src/manager.cc -O3 -w -std=c++11 -Iinclude -MMD
g++ -o obj/interface.o -c src/interface.cc -O3 -w -std=c++11 -Iinclude -MMD
...
g++ -o bin/bnmc ... obj/manager.o obj/interface.o ... -L***/lib64 -Wl,-Bstatic -lbnc -lgsl -ldlib -lbddc -ldlib -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -lreadline -ltermcap -lgmp -lgmpxx -Wl,-R***/lib64 -Wl,-R***/usr/lib64 
duplicate symbol bnmc::ModelCounter<(bnmc::ModelType)0>::Read()    in:
    obj/modelcounter_pwpbdd.o
    obj/modelcounter.o
duplicate symbol bnmc::ModelCounter<(bnmc::ModelType)1>::Traverse(std::vector<bnmc::EvidenceEntry, std::allocator<bnmc::EvidenceEntry> > const&) in:
    obj/modelcounter.o
    obj/modelcounter_wpbdd.o
duplicate symbol bnmc::ModelCounter<(bnmc::ModelType)2>::Traverse(std::vector<bnmc::EvidenceEntry, std::allocator<bnmc::EvidenceEntry> > const&) in:
    obj/modelcounter.o
    obj/modelcounter_obdd.o
...
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:297: recipe for target 'bin/bnmc' failed
make: *** [bin/bnmc] Error 1
```

I know what this error means, but I do not know why it only occurs on the Macports version of gcc:

```
> gcc --version
gcc (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_1) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It also fails with gcc 4.9.4 and 6.3.0. It does not fail on my linux machine using:

```
> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Some information on the code. The compiler indicated duplicates are template class member functions. It is setup as follows. The class declaration is in a header file.

```
// someclass.h
template <typename T>
class someclass {
    public:
        T somefunction();
        T someotherfunction();
        ...
};
```

The definitions are in 2 source files.

```
// someclass.cc
template <typename T>
T someclass<T>::somefunction(){
    // foo
}
template <typename T>
T someclass<T>::someotherfunction(){
    // bar
}
...

template class someclass<int>;
template class someclass<...>;
...
```

And a separate specialization file:

```
// specialsomeclass.cc
template <>
int someclass<int>::somefuntion(){
    // foo
}
```

I can reason why this would go wrong, as `somefunction` is defined in 2 source files, but I do not understand why only the macports version of gcc complains about this. Is there something I can or must do to get this to compile?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And show us the *complete* and *full* build output with the error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The source code provided should already be minimal and complete, simply remove the lines that contain dots. The compiler honestly does not say anything else except for indicating the files that contain the duplicates (e.g., in someclass.cc and specialsomeclass.cc).

Comment: "The definitions are in 2 source files" - then you'll get duplicate code in the corresponding `.o` files. (Having specializations in a separate source sounds very problematic.)

Comment: @Mat I agree. I already found it to be surprising that the linux GCC compiler accepts this, although a template specialization should be allowed to overwrite the general template function definition.